# I have a function taking some data attributes which is not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

To give you some context.
I have a picture of a person with a specific border color, when you click on that picture it opens a new panel with the same picture and the same border color. It is working properly on Chrome but not on Firefox.

This is on Chrome:
[image]

And this is on Firefox:[image]

As you may see, on Firefox it has a different border color(black) on the left which is the picture on the new panel I mentioned.

This is the JS function which takes the border color of the main picture and put it on the picture of the side panel:

```
var showInfo = function (evt) {
    //console.log("---"+evt);
    evt.preventDefault();
    var id = this.parentNode.id;
    var info = APP.chart.getUser(id) || {};
    info['class'] = $(this).data('class');
    if($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('disabled') !== true){
        APP.sidebar.load(info);
    }
};

var circleColor = function () {
    $('[data-action="user-picture-chart"]').click(function(e) {
        $('[data-action="user-picture-sidebar"]').css('border-color', $(e.target).css('border-color'));
    });
};

var bindEventsToUI = function () {
    $('.js-user-info img').on('click', showInfo);
    $('.js-user-info strong').on('click', showInfo);
    circleColor();
};
```

This is the template for the main picture:

```
<img class="user__picture" data-action="user-picture-chart"
     src="assets/images/profile-picture/{{this.picture}}" />
```

And this is the template for the panel on the left:

```
<img class="user__picture" src="{%picture%}" data-action="user-picture-sidebar" />
```

Default css for .user__picture

```
&__picture {
    border: 4px solid #000;
}
```

And this is the default color of the picture selected in the screenshots:

```
&--mngr {
    .user__picture {
        border-color: #bebebe;
    }
}
```

So, as you may see, that is the whole code related to that issue which is just not working on Firefox.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In the `circleColor` function, is the e.target the same element/node when debugging in Firefox and Chrome? Also check that `$('[data-action="user-picture-sidebar"]')` is returning the same thing in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding !important rule in your css, I think firefox is reading your default css.

```
&--mngr {
    .user__picture {
        border-color: #bebebe!important;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)